# How to get cpp files from different directories compiled into one folder?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, gnu-make

I have a number of C++ files distributed in several folders.

```
a_library/
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
    category1/
        file3.cpp
        file4.cpp
```

They are guaruanteed to be uniquely named. I want to compile all those C++ files to seperate Object-files in the `obj/` directory.

I have a list of all source-files with relative path, and their corresponding destination-names.

```
a_library/file1.cpp
a_library/file2.cpp
a_library/category1/file3.cpp
a_library/category1/file4.cpp

obj/file1.obj
obj/file2.obj
obj/file3.obj
obj/file4.obj
```

How can I make a rule that will convert a C++ file from the first list to a object-file from the second one?

These attempts do *not* work:

```
obj/%.obj: %:cpp
    # ...

%.obj: %.cpp
    # ...

.cpp.obj:
    # ...
```

I would like to not write rules like this:

```
obj/%.obj: a_library/%.cpp
    # ...

obj/%.obj: a_library/category1/%.cpp
    # ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting `VPATH`:

```sh
VPATH = a_library:a_library/category1
obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

And to add complete file list (I would recommend you explicitely list the files, do not use `$(wildcard ...)` function) and linking of the application:

```sh
files := main.cpp $(wildcard a_library/*.cpp) a_library/category1/file.cpp

obj/application: $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(notdir $(files)))
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+
```

The `$(wildcard)` has an annoying tendency to pick up anything in the directories, like one-off test files or temporaries (if they happen to have a fitting name: `~file.cpp`).

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of: just build them inplace with a simple rule and then make a "collection phase" moving the ".o" files to a single folder.

Make a "collect_objs" target which depends on your $(OBJS) and then your "main" target must depend on "collect_objs".

The traversal can be done using shell

```
dirs := $(shell find ./ -type d)
collect_objs: $(dirs)
      for d in $+; do \
          mv *.o YourDestDir/*.o
      done
```

Of course, this implies using UnxUtils package (with 'find' and 'mv') or Cygwin since you are on Windows.

The other option is to generate the targets for each of your .c/.cpp file explicitly, using some tool. Grab python, traverse source directories and for each .c/.cpp file write

```
obj/file_name.o:
       gcc -c path/fo/file_name.c -o obj/file_name.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) to make the build configuration for you.

Some time ago I set up a simple example project on [github](https://github.com/moooeeeep/cmake_sample).

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to have a `Makefile` in each folder and call recursively with `include`

This was my first two hits on 10^100:

http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makerecurs.html

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly related to this question as it doesn't have to do with Make, though I'd like to show how I compile my projects now, 3 years later. [Craftr](https://github.com/craftr-build/craftr) is a Python based meta build system that encourages indirect out-of-tree builds (eg. a `build` in the working tree). Building object files and cresting a static library is as easy as

```
# craftr_module(my_project)
from craftr import *
from craftr.ext.platform import cxx, ar
objects = cxx.compile(
  sources = path.platform('**/*.cpp'),
)
lib = ar.staticlib(
  output = 'myproj',
  inputs = [objects],
)
```

Running `craftr -eb` will result with the following structure of build products

```
Craftfile
file1.c
file2.c
category1/
  file3.c
  file4.c
build/
  my_project/
    obj/
      file1.o
      file2.o
      category1/
        file3.o
        file4.o
    libmyproj.a
```